# Git reset shows one item to be fetch from the server

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-commit

I am new with GIT and by mistake, I pushed a code to the server which was not part of the current branch.

My Commit history for `BranchX` was like this (commit message modified for eg.) :

```
ca184982 - Changes I pushed mistakenly 
fa761347 - Some good changes 
2a839483 - Previous commits
```

After checking a few SO post and blogs on the internet, I execute below command:

> git reset --hard fa761347

After executing the above command, when I synced my branch it's showing that 1 commit has to pull from the server but actually, I want to delete that commit from the server also.

Can you point out what I did wrong? or is there any other command that I have to execute?

Comment: when you do a reset, your local copy is reset to the 'some good changes' commit head. Unless you push it to the remote you'll see that the remote is ahead by a commit. Try pushing it after reset? (if you're the only person pushing to the remote  consider using --force flag.)

Comment: Thanks. On executing `git push -f` it worked.

Comment: @Dishant Since your problem has been solved, you can add the solution as an answer and mark it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete or revert the current commit on the **remote** branch.

I suggest reverting and pushing the reverted commit

1. `git pull` - this will get the bad commit
2. `git revert ca184982` - this creates and commits a commit which is a reversal of `ca184982` to your local branch
3. `git push` - this pushes the reverse of the bad commit onto the remote branch.
4. All done

---

In your comment you said that `git push -f` worked but:

- You don't always can do it (server rules); and
- It can create tricky situations when others do a `pull` before you `push -f`

---

Re:comment:

After this the history would look something like this:

```
 xxxxxxxx - Revert of 'ca184982'
 ca184982 - Changes I pushed mistakenly 
 fa761347 - Some good changes 
 2a839483 - Previous commits
```

Comment: Thanks. But why I need `git pull` as I am on the same branch?

Comment: You are not on *the same* branch - there are two branches - one local, one on the server. Very often branches with the same name are connected so when you 'git pull' git knows which **remote** branch to get data from. This connection (what points to what) is in your git config files.

Comment: Can you let me know how my commit order will look like? will it shrink to
fa761347 - Some good changes 
2a839483 - Previous commits   or it will be
ca184982 - Reverted changes
fa761347 - Some good changes 
2a839483 - Previous commits

Comment: Thanks. It clarified my doubt. But if I don't want to leave any trace than `git push -f` is only the option and if I am not able to execute because of the server rules than there's no alternative, right?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to leave a trace `push -f` would be the way. If server doesn't allow `-f` then the revert commit is the way.